# MacBook Pro, external display black screen with 1680x1050

Tags: macbook-pro, vga-adapter, display

I have bought a new monitor Samsung SyncMaster 2243. I have been using it normally on windows with 1680x1050 resolution for almost a year now. I tried to connect it to my MacBook Pro via VGA to Mini display port adapter. It worked fine but 1440x900 resolution showed up. So I tried to set it to native display resolution 1680x1050 and now only thing I see is black screen. It works only for a few seconds per minute approximately. There are flashes. I cant lower the refresh rate, there is 60Mhz and no option to select lower.

Do you have any ideas what to try? Apple documentation says that Mini display port to VGA adapter supports 1920 resolution.

Thank you

Comment: I use a MiniDisplayPort -> VGA adapter at 1080 without trouble. Does the PC you tested with use the VGA connection?

Comment: Yes of course it does.

Answer (score 1):

Apple today released an update that addresses external display support in Macbook Pros.  Give that a try.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try. Can you provide a link to the update with more info? (I suppose I have to check for updates on my mac to download it automatically, but no updates are found).

Comment: Here is one http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1382 
and another http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1381 

Apply both if you have the latest Macbook Pro